# Send copy of Laravel notification to admin

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I am working on a module where you can create users and link them to specific restaurants. When a user is created, the manager of the restaurant and if set, the contact person of that restaurant gets a mail notification with the message that a new user is created and linked to that restaurant.

Now I'm trying to achieve the next case: when the notification is sent, al the added admin email addresses need to be notified with the same email, just like a bcc. But when I'm using the bcc and the notification is sent to like 2 users, the bcc will also send twice.

Since I can't add just email addresses to the `Notification::send()` method, I can't achieve this in one line of code. My current Notification:

```
Notification::send($users, new UserCreated($params));
```

How I think it should be done:

```
$emailAddresses = ['email1@test.com', 'email2@test.com']
Notification::send([$users, $emailAddresses], new UserCreated($params);
```

How can I achieve this in the right way?

Comment: You're missing `)` at the end of `Notification::send(` by the way

Comment: You can add one more user to `$users` variable, can't you?

Comment: @Tarasovych yes, but the admin emails are not always users objects, just an email address

Comment: The easiest way might be for you to create users with those email addresses. You could maybe add a role column and then give them an "admin" role so don't have to hard-code those email addresses.

Comment: @DelenaMalan Not sure why I didn't think about that, maybe that's the best solution indeed. It's Friday, my brain already has stopped working ^^

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#specifying-delivery-channels):

> On-Demand Notifications
>
> Sometimes you may need to send a notification to someone who is not
>   stored as a "user" of your application. Using the Notification::route
>   method, you may specify ad-hoc notification routing information before
>   sending the notification:

```php
Notification::route('mail', 'taylor@example.com')
            ->route('nexmo', '5555555555')
            ->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

So, you can try something like this:

```php
Notification::route('mail', 'email1@test.com')
            ->route('mail', 'email2@test.com')
            ->notify(new UserCreated($params));
```

[route](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Notifications/AnonymousNotifiable.html#method_route) method